# CTest run only incrementally build tests

Tags: cmake, ctest

Our large repository has a lot of different unit tests executables.
If I build our repo incremetally, cmake only builds those libraries and executables, which need to be build.

If I now start the tests via ctest all tests are executed. Also those tests, which have not changed and thus will give the same result as last time, will be started.

Is there a way to only run tests that changed?

Comment: To my knowledge CTest does not support that natively. Did you have a look at this, maybe you can adapt it for your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729103/running-only-changed-or-failed-tests-with-cmake-ctest

Comment: I might be wrong here, but isn't it possible for an executable to not need modification while a shared library it depends on does? In that case, might you also need/want to get that executable tested as well? In that case, you might want to modify your question to include things that transitively depend on any targets that got rebuilt.